# Is it okay to use an extremely diluted essential oil pillow spray if I have cats?

Tags: cats, health

I have a specific pillow spray that really relaxes me at night. I spray my pillow and blanket just a couple times each, and the cats don’t usually come to bed for HOURS, so it’s definitely dry by the time they get there. Water is the first ingredient, and the essential oils are listed FAR down at the bottom… so far I haven’t seen anything out of the ordinary for them, but I’m worried because the oils in the spray are pine and eucalyptus…

It’s so diluted and I don’t spray it near them, I don’t even pet them for a bit after I put on the lotion (same oils)… will they be alright?

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I would avoid spraying the oil anywhere a cat could touch. Oil doesn't evaporate as quickly as water, so even hours of spraying your pillow, there are probably traces of the essential oils left on the fabric. Cats can actually absorb these traces via the skin on their feet, but at a very slow rate.

The problem with most essential oils is that cats don't produce the enzymes to metabolize or neutralize them. So even trace amounts can accumulate over a long time. By the time your cat shows any symptoms, you probably won't think about essential oil poisoning because you've *always* used the spray and nothing ever happened, *until now*.

So my suggestion is to apply the spray to a piece of cloth (like a handkerchif) close to your head, but not touching your pillow or bed. One more safety layer is to drip the spray onto the cloth instead of spraying it, to avoid spreading the essential oil to surrounding surfaces. If you want to go super safe and fancy at the same time, consider an incense bowl with a lid that lets the aroma spray evaporate but doesn't let your cats touch the cloth inside.

These are some random examples of incense bowls I found in various online shops, I'm not affiliated with any of them:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think essential oils in fact do evaporate?

Comment: @Stephie Yes, you're right. I realize now that my phrasing was poor. I meant to say that essential oils don't evaporate as quickly as water.